PHP Sort a multidimensional array by date start, or if uquals, by date end
I need to sort an array containing a date start and a date end.
To sort by date start I use this function:
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  return new DateTime($a['datetime']) <=> new DateTime($b['datetime']);
});

but in case an element has the same date start to another one, i need then sort by date end.
And don't know how to do this. Anyt suggest?
Example array
$array = [
0 => [
        "id" => 1
        "start" => 2024-07-24 05:00,
        "end" => 2024-07-25 14:00
    ],

1 => [
       "id" => 2
        "start" => 2024-07-22 06:00,
        "end" => 2024-07-22 08:00
    ],

2 => [
        "id" => 3
        "start" => 2024-07-27 10:00,
        "end" => 2024-07-28 11:00
    ],

3 => [
        "id" => 4
        "start" => 2024-07-22 06:00,
        "end" => 2024-07-22 07:00
    ]

]

With my example I expected this order id: 4, 2, 1, 3 (because id 4 and 2 has same start, but id 4 ends before)

I assume there is no datetime key in your array and it is rather those start and end keys.
So, compare the start datetimes first. If they are not equal, return the result given from the spaceship operator(<=>).
If they are equal, return the result returned from the end datetimes.
<?php

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  $startDiff = new DateTime($a['start']) <=> new DateTime($b['start']);

  if ($startDiff != 0) {
    return $startDiff;
  }

  return new DateTime($a['end']) <=> new DateTime($b['end']);
});

